# Sorting item from JComboBox

Tags: sorting, jdbc, jcombobox

I'm having problem sorting my items from jcombobox, here are my codes.

```
public void fillCombo() 
{       
    String dataSourceName = "CheckWriterDB";
    String dbURL = "jdbc:odbc:" + dataSourceName;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "", "");   

        st = con.createStatement();

        st.execute("select Suppliers from SuppliersTable");

        rs = st.getResultSet();

        if(rs!=null)
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                temp = rs.getString(1);             
                listOfSuppliersCombo.addItem(temp1);

            }
        }
        st.close();
        con.close();        
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Your error is:  " + e);
    } 
}
```

Can anybody help me on how to sort the item shown in my JComboBox, data source of the items shown in my combobox is from my DATABASE. Thank you so much.

Comment: put `con/st close()` in `finally` block!

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` in your query to retrieve data ordered from your database

```
st.execute("select Suppliers from SuppliersTable order by <fields>");
```

Syntax: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by_(SQL)

Comment: Thank you so much, i try to check it out.

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience sir, but the result of the Syntax (order by '<fields>') did not solve my problem.  What it did is sort my data from the last item to the first item on my database, I want to sort them Alphabetically, I have an idea of passing my String temp to an object so i could use the sort() but i don't now how. I would be very appreciative if you could Tolerate my inexperience. Is syntax complete sir? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I've already figured it out. Thanks again.